# browsing of local server through iphone app

Tags: iphone

can anyone  help me to make the iphone app which can browse the files of the computer which is available on local network?

Answer (score 0):

In short, you'll have to create a server on the local machine that is accessed from the iphone.  On the iphone side, you'll have to create the client that accesses this server.  Use google to see if you can find some examples of directory servers and see if you can adapt them to your needs.

This is a huge topic, one which cannot be answered here in 100 (or probably even 1000) words.

**Edit**

Think something like [openLDAP](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-iphoneapp/?ca=drs-)

Comment: Yes i want to develop a iphone app which can show the list of files of my local system (which shared on the network) i didn't find right help for iphone app.Please if you may provide me some link that can help me to develop this.